# Where does firefox get the system theme from?

Tags: firefox, themes, darkmode

I am writing a bash script to switch system theme between dark and light whenever necessary (on Linux Mint 20.3). I could make it work for the overall OS theme, the terminal theme, and some gnome applications on flatpak.

With this, I expected that Mozilla Firefox will switch theme automatically, as its theme has been set to `System theme`. However, the Firefox theme does not change. It would be helpful if someone could point me in the right direction to implement this.

In short, I am looking for *at least one* of the following:

1. The manner in which Firefox determines the system theme on Linux Mint.
2. The commands to force Firefox to follow a particular theme.

Thanks in advance. Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo Current Theme: $(gsettings get org.cinnamon.theme name)
elif [ $1 == "dark" ]
then
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Yaru-dark'
    flatpak override --user --env=GTK_THEME='Yaru-dark'
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.theme name 'Mint-Y-Dark'
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Mint-Y-Dark"
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences theme "Mint-Y-Dark"
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Mint-Y-Dark'
    gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default f02cd96e-20b4-4146-a6aa-75f5da6a65b2 
elif [ "$1" = "light" ]
then
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Yaru-light'
    flatpak override --user --env=GTK_THEME='Yaru-light'
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.theme name 'Mint-Y'
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Mint-Y"
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences theme "Mint-Y"
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Mint-Y'
    gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9
else
    echo "Unknown argument"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for might be simply:

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme 'prefer-dark'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme 'prefer-light'
```

Comment: Tried this, but returned an error: `No such key "color-scheme"`

Comment: According to https://github.com/GNOME/gsettings-desktop-schemas/blob/master/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.interface.gschema.xml.in, it seems like `prefer-dark` and `prefer-light` are valid values for `org.gnome.desktop.GDesktopColorScheme`, but this id doesn't exist on my computer.

Comment: @kksagar It was added on [2021-09-19](https://github.com/GNOME/gsettings-desktop-schemas/commit/e3c2c421d78a8bfff466ad2180781cbaacce0319) so maybe it's not yet in the release that Mint 20.3 runs?

Comment: @ChrisWesseling Thank you, will try to check that. The gsettings version number is 2.64.6, I couldn't find the version number corresponding to the date that you mentioned.

Comment: @kksagar Maybe the gsettings repo has tags?